# Right align horizontal seaborn barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

How can I make the horizontal seaborn barplot right aligned / mirrored

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
y = [4, 6, 3]
sns.barplot(x=y, y=x, orient='h')
plt.show()
```

The default horizontal barplot looks like this
[image]

I want to have something like this (with proper xticks)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to invert the x axis, you can use:

```
ax.invert_xaxis()
```

Then, in order to move the labels to the right, you can use:

```
plt.tick_params(axis = 'y', left = False, right = True, labelleft = False, labelright = True)
```

or, shorter:

```
ax.yaxis.tight_right()
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
y = [4, 6, 3]
ax = sns.barplot(x=y, y=x, orient='h')

ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `matplotlib` x-axis limits. An easy way to do this is capture the `Axes` instance returned by `sns.barplot`, and then use `ax.set_xlim` on that.

Then you can use `ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')` and `ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')` to move the ticks and axis labels to the right.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
y = [4, 6, 3]
ax = sns.barplot(x=y, y=x, orient='h')
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[1], ax.get_xlim()[0])

ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')

plt.show()
```

[image]
In that example, I grabbed the existing limits and just reversed them. Alternatively, you could just set them explicitly, making sure the first number is the upper limit, to ensure the reversed scale. For example:

```
ax.set_xlim(6.5, 0)
```

A final alternative is to use the built in `ax.invert_xaxis()` function